# ActionListeners don't work in modal JDialog

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jdialog

I wrote my own class for modal dialog, but when I call it from my code there is no any reaction on buttons clicking. 
If I define `setModal(false)` everything works great. 
I suppose there is some troubles with concurrency, but I'm not sure about it.
Where is my mistake?

```
public class PauseTaskDialog extends JDialog {

private JPanel contentPane;
private JButton buttonOK;
private JButton buttonCancel;
private JCheckBox prioritisingCheckBox;
private JCheckBox simultaneousWorkCheckBox;
private JCheckBox problemsWithDataCheckBox;
private JTextArea comment;

private String taskID;

public PauseTaskDialog(String task) {

    this.setContentPane(contentPane);
    this.setModal(true);
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    this.pack();

    this.setTitle("Task pause reasons");

    this.taskID = task;

    comment.setFont(comment.getFont().deriveFont(14f));
    comment.setLineWrap(true);
    comment.setWrapStyleWord(true);

    buttonOK.addActionListener(e -> {
        onOK();
    });

    buttonCancel.addActionListener(e -> {
        onCancel();
    });

    this.setVisible(true);
}


private void onOK() {
    // some code here        
}

private void onCancel() {
    // some code there
}
}
```

I call the dialog from my code this way:

```
PauseTaskDialog dialog = new PauseTaskDialog(taskID);
```

Comment: add your java version

Comment: @AdeelAhmed , 1.8.0_131

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Based on the code you've provided, nothing seem to be added to the `contentPane`, so I'm not sure what you'd expect, other than an empty dialog :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Dialog.html#setModal(boolean)):

> Note: changing modality of the visible dialog may have no effect until it is hidden and then shown again.

Try calling `setModal(true)` before `setVisible`.

But `setModal` is deprecated, you should call `setModalityType` instead (the type you need is likely `APPLICATION_MODAL`), check this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/modality.html).
it has nothing to do with JButton listeners not working, if you can CLICK on JButton then it means you are running their listeners(if there are any),if you cant click them(JButton has animation that shows that they are being clicked) then they are hidden/not on front, it has nothing to do with concurrency.

Comment: The problem is that the button click animation is running, but an action for this button isn't. The code inside ActionListeners does not start. The only action in this dialog I'm able to perform is to click Close (X) button on window. When I remove modality everything works fine.

Comment: [`setModel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Dialog.html#setModal-boolean-) is marked as deprecated, the `modilityType` simply provides more flexible control - just saying ;)

Comment: Literally five minutes ago it hit me, I got what you meant. You meant to paste the line `setModal()` **right before** (not simply somewhere before) the line `setVisible()`. I'm sorry for misunderstanding, English isn't my native language. Have a nice day :D